# Selecting by ID in Hibernate + Scala

Tags: scala, hibernate

This works in Hibernate/Java:

```
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        User user =  (User) session.get(User.class, user_id);
```

I need to migrate this class to Scala, I tried the below but it says that cannot find `User`:

```
        val user = session.get(User.class, user_id)
```

Another try that also fails:

```
        val user = session.get[User](user_id)
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `classOf` and `asInstanceOf`:

```
val user = session.get(classOf[User], user_id).asInstanceOf[User]
```